# Working with jquery elements and numbers

Tags: jquery, dry

```js
$('select.farbe-1').change(function() {
  var chosen = $(this).find(":selected").text().toLowerCase();
  $('img.color-1').attr('src', 'http://www.schiendorfer.info/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/bestellungen/img/color/' + chosen + '.jpg');
});

$('select.farbe-2').change(function() {
  var chosen = $(this).find(":selected").text().toLowerCase();
  $('img.color-2').attr('src', 'http://www.schiendorfer.info/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/bestellungen/img/color/' + chosen + '.jpg');
});

$('select.farbe-3').change(function() {
  var chosen = $(this).find(":selected").text().toLowerCase();
  $('img.color-3').attr('src', 'http://www.schiendorfer.info/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/bestellungen/img/color/' + chosen + '.jpg');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="product-choice choice-1">

  <img class="color-1" src="http://www.schiendorfer.info/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/bestellungen/img/color/blue.jpg">

  <select class="farbe-1" name="farbe_1">
    <option value="3">Black</option>
    <option value="1">Blue</option>
    <option value="2">Green</option>
    <option value="4">Orange</option>
    <option value="0" selected="">Red</option>
  </select>

</div>

<div class="product-choice choice-2">

  <img class="color-2" src="http://www.schiendorfer.info/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/bestellungen/img/color/blue.jpg">

  <select class="farbe-2" name="farbe_2">
    <option value="3">Black</option>
    <option value="1">Blue</option>
    <option value="2">Green</option>
    <option value="4">Orange</option>
    <option value="0" selected="">Red</option>
  </select>

</div>

<div class="product-choice choice-3">

  <img class="color-3" src="http://www.schiendorfer.info/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/bestellungen/img/color/blue.jpg">

  <select class="farbe-3" name="farbe_3">
    <option value="3">Black</option>
    <option value="1">Blue</option>
    <option value="2">Green</option>
    <option value="4">Orange</option>
    <option value="0" selected="">Red</option>
  </select>

</div>
```

I have the code above and it works fine. But I have to repeat this 10 times. You can easily see that the only difference is `select.farbe-**x**` and `img.color-**x**`

How can I reduce the code and write this "professionally"?

Edit: I have added a Snippet ;)

Comment: Use DOM traversal to link the element that raised the event to the one which you want to amend. If you can edit your question to include an HTML sample, I can give you an actual example of this.

Comment: The structure of the HTML would be vital to answering your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of numbered classes, give them all the same class, and use `.index()` and `.eq()` to get the current position and use that to find the corresponding element to change.

```js
$('select.farbe').change(function() {
  var index = $("select.farbe").index(this)
  var chosen = $(this).find(":selected").text().toLowerCase();
  $('img.color').eq(index).attr('src', 'http://www.schiendorfer.info/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/bestellungen/img/color/' + chosen + '.jpg');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="product-choice choice-1">

  <img class="color" src="http://www.schiendorfer.info/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/bestellungen/img/color/blue.jpg">

  <select class="farbe" name="farbe_1">
    <option value="3">Black</option>
    <option value="1">Blue</option>
    <option value="2">Green</option>
    <option value="4">Orange</option>
    <option value="0" selected="">Red</option>
  </select>

</div>

<div class="product-choice choice-2">

  <img class="color" src="http://www.schiendorfer.info/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/bestellungen/img/color/blue.jpg">

  <select class="farbe" name="farbe_2">
    <option value="3">Black</option>
    <option value="1">Blue</option>
    <option value="2">Green</option>
    <option value="4">Orange</option>
    <option value="0" selected="">Red</option>
  </select>

</div>

<div class="product-choice choice-3">

  <img class="color" src="http://www.schiendorfer.info/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/bestellungen/img/color/blue.jpg">

  <select class="farbe" name="farbe_3">
    <option value="3">Black</option>
    <option value="1">Blue</option>
    <option value="2">Green</option>
    <option value="4">Orange</option>
    <option value="0" selected="">Red</option>
  </select>

</div>
```

Or, since the dropdown is always right after the image, you can simply use

```
$(this).prev().attr('src', 'http://www.schiendorfer.info/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/bestellungen/img/color/' + chosen + '.jpg');
```

Comment: I like this idea, but i can't make it work. Somehow it always changes the last image item. Coudl you please provide me a snippet?

Comment: Thanks very much! Before there was a ; too much, I think.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this one

```
$('select[name*="farbe-"]').change(function () {
    var $index=$(this).attr('name').split('-')[1];
    var $colVal=$(this).find(':selected').val();
    $('img.color-'+$index).attr('src','http://www.schiendorfer.info/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/bestellungen/img/color/'+$colVal+'.jpg'); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I've done quite a bit of similar stuff, and I like to include the numeric id value as a data-attribute on the tags. In this case, I would call it data-color. This way, I can easily access which element had the change function, simply by getting it's id. Then I use this ID to change the relevant other elements, who I have given the same ID's.

I do not have access to the image files you link to, so I've added a span behind each select box, which are updated instead. The principal is the same:

Working fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/52yfekzx/

Javascript:

```
$('select.farbe').change(function(){
    var chosen = $(this).find(":selected").text().toLowerCase();
    var colorID = $(this).data("color");
    $('span.color[data-color="'+colorID+'"]').text(chosen); 
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="product-choice choice-1">

<img class="color"  data-color="1" src="http://www.schiendorfer.info/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/bestellungen/img/color/blue.jpg">

<select class="farbe" data-color="1" name="farbe_1">
    <option value="3">Black</option>
    <option value="1">Blue</option>
    <option value="2">Green</option>
    <option value="4">Orange</option>
    <option value="0" selected="">Red</option>                
</select>
<span class="color" data-color="1"></span>
</div>

<div class="product-choice choice-2">

<img class="color" data-color="2" src="http://www.schiendorfer.info/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/bestellungen/img/color/blue.jpg">

<select class="farbe" data-color="2"  name="farbe_2">
    <option value="3">Black</option>
    <option value="1">Blue</option>
    <option value="2">Green</option>
    <option value="4">Orange</option>
    <option value="0" selected="">Red</option>                
</select>
<span class="color" data-color="2"></span>          
</div>

<div class="product-choice choice-3">

<img class="color" data-color="3" src="http://www.schiendorfer.info/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/bestellungen/img/color/blue.jpg">

<select class="farbe" data-color="3" name="farbe_3">
    <option value="3">Black</option>
    <option value="1">Blue</option>
    <option value="2">Green</option>
    <option value="4">Orange</option>
    <option value="0" selected="">Red</option>                
</select>
<span class="color" data-color="3"></span>

</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do something like that:

```
for(var i = 1; i <= 10; i++){
    $('select.farbe-'+i).change(function(){
        var chosen = $(this).find(":selected").text().toLowerCase();
        $('img.color-'+i).attr('src','/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/bestellungen/img/color/'+chosen+'.jpg'); 
    });
}
```

As far as I understood your problem, that solves it. You can concatened strings inside jQuery's keys.

Comment: This will always select `img.color-11`, not the image relative to the select.